# Reading all classes under a package or reading classes with same Metadata in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, class, metadata, package, introspection

I am doing an Actionscript 3.0 project which involves introspection. I am wondering if there is a way to get all the classes within a given package structure. 
    For e.g. Say there are three as3 classes:
com.example.test.classOne
com.example.test.classTwo
com.example.test.classThree

I want to be able to say

```
  getClassesUnderPackageName("com.example.test");
```

and get back

```
  "com.example.test::classOne"
  "com.example.test::classTwo"
  "com.example.test::classThree".
```

Is there a way to do that?

If this is not possible, is there a way to read classes which have the same metadata?

E.g. If all the mentioned classes have the same metadata [MetadataName(type="example")] defined, is there a way to say

```
   getClassesWithSameMetadata("MetadataName");
```

and get back

```
   "com.example.test::classOne"
   "com.example.test::classTwo"
   "com.example.test::classThree".
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [flash.utils.describeType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) to return XML data containing this information.  it works differently on base classes, like `flash.display.Sprite`, but for custom classes/directories, you can write something like this:

```
package branchA.branchB.branchC
{
//Imports
import flash.utils.describeType;

//Class
public class Test
    {
    //Constructor
    public function Test()
        {
        trace(describeType(this).@name);
        }
    }
}

//OUTPUT:  branchA.branchB.branchC::Test
```

if you wanted to return the base class, you could write something like this:

```
package
{
//Imports
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.describeType;

//Class
public class Test extends Sprite
    {
    //Constructor
    public function Test()
        {
        trace(describeType(this).@base);
        }
    }
}

//OUTPUT:  flash.display::Sprite
```

there is lots of other useful information you can get by parsing the returned XML data of describeType.

---

**Update:**

class objects do not need to have been instantiated first in order to retrieve their information via describeType().  you could build a public static function (or whatever) which accepts an array of your class objects and returns an array of strings containing the required describeType data.

something like this:

```
package
{
import flash.utils.describeType;

final public class Describe
    {
    public static function packageNames(classObjects:Array):Vector.<String>
        {
        var names:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();

        for each    (var classObject in classObjects)
                    names.push(describeType(classObject.@name.toString()));

        return names;
        }
    }
}
```

then from anywhere in your program, you can pass an array of all the classes like this:

```
var names:Vector.<String> = Describe.packageNames(new Array(classOne, classTwo, classThree));
trace(names);

//Output:
//com.example.test::classOne
//com.example.test::classTwo
//com.example.test::classThree
```

Comment: This will work only if I call the constructor or a function that contain "describeType" explicitly. My question is if there is a helper function that can return all the classes within a package by just calling a function similar to describeType.

Comment: i don't quite follow.  there is certainly no ready-made helper function for this highly uncommon problem.  you would use describeType to make your own static function or whatever you want.

Comment: Oh ok. I was looking for something like the annotations that Java uses. But, I can work with describeType(). Thank you!

Comment: i've updated my answer to give you an example of how you could use describeType for your requirements.

Comment: You've still hardcoded `classOne, classTwo, classThree`. Sort of goes against the question as originally asked.

Comment: I'd recommend using [AS3 Commons Reflect](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/) instead of `describeType` itself. It provides a great API so you don't have to work with `describeType`'s XML output.

Answer (score 1):

There's no inbuilt mechanism for finding classes without already knowing the class name. :(

However if you load in a SWF as a ByteArray then it's possible to iterate through the classes in it.

This might be overkill for what you want.

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=175

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AS3 Commons Bytecode](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode). It allows you to do [Bytecode based reflection](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/introduction.html). You can list all classes (you'll need to filter those if you just want a particular package), list classes with certain metadata or classes that implement a certain interface.